# Is it possible to convert greek word to greek symbol in a text using PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to convert greek words to greek symbols in a text using PHP?

For example,

```
$string = "alpha + beta = gamma";
```

Converts to `"&alpha; + &beta; = &gamma;"` (α + β = γ)

Comment: I don't think so...but you can use str_replace

Comment: You mean Greek _letters_, not words? For that I’d simply use `str_replace` and two arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) with an array of translations:

```
<?php

$translations = [
    'alpha' => '&alpha;',
    'beta'  => '&beta;',
    'gamma' => '&gamma;',
];


$str = 'alpha + beta = gamma';

echo strtr($str, $translations);
```

Yields:

> α + β = γ

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use str_replace. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

For instance

```
$string = "alpha + beta = gamma";
$greeks = array('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'zeta', 'eta', 'theta');
$htmls  = array('&alpha;', '&beta;', '&gamma;', '&delta;', '&epsilon;', '&zeta;', '&theta;'); // et c.

$greekString = str_replace($greeks, $htmls, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example,

```
echo preg_replace('/[A-Za-z][a-z]+/', '&$0;', $string);
```

would do. See [here](https://eval.in/517690).

It surrounds all sequences of lowercase characters with `&` and `;`. If you want to do that in a text which contains arbitrary words, replace the square brackets with `(alpha|Alpha|beta|Beta|gamma|...)` or put these into an array.

Comment: This won't give the desired result if your string wasn't entirely greek symbols

Comment: Seen that sentence which starts with _If you want to_ in the last paragraph?